# Instead of displaying the message content, the browser automatically downloads the EML file

Tags: java, email

```
public void showMessageContent(@RequestParam("mailNum") Integer mailNum, HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse response) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    User user = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    Message message = MailUtils.getMail(user, mailNum);
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    try{
        if(!message.isMimeType("multipart/mixed"))
        {
            response.setContentType("message/rfc822");
            message.writeTo(out);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but the Browser can't display the e-mail content,it always automatically download EML files 。
How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that an Internet browser is able to read EML files.

When you save a mail from Mozilla Thunderbird and you want to open it in Chrome, you'll have to save it as HTML file.

What browser are you trying to use ?

Comment: chrome , firefox , edge ，I have tried them all,  they can't display email content, always download files.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying; a web browser cannot open a EML file. You have to output it in HTML then the browser can read it